# How to slideup two elements at the same time using css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, css-transitions

I'm trying to create a slider with 2 buttons (arrows up & down), when the user clicks the up arrow, the current element (which is centered) in the slider slides up and fades (i.e. hides or the opacity becomes 0), and the next element slides up from the bottom of the screen until the opacity becomes 1.

But I can't seem to make it work using just CSS. I managed to replicate it using javascript (Vuejs), but it is very inefficient.

```js
<template>
  <transition appear>
    <div v-if="condition" class="trans-container">
      <slot></slot>
    </div>
  </transition>
</template>
<script>
  import velocity from 'velocity-animate'
  export default {
    name: "Slide",
    props: {
      condition: {
        default: true,
        type: Boolean
      },
      direction: {
        type: String
      }
    },
    methods: {
      // --------
      // ENTERING
      // --------

beforeEnter: function (el) {
        // el.style.opacity = 0
        Velocity(el, {
          translateY: this.direction === 'up' ? '100%' : '-100%',
          opacity: 0
        }, {
          duration: 300
        });
      },
      // the done callback is optional when
      // used in combination with CSS
      enter: function (el, done) {
        Velocity(el, {
          translateY: '0%',
          opacity: 1
        }, {
          duration: 300
        });
        // ...
        // done()
      },
      afterEnter: function (el) {

      },
      enterCancelled: function (el) {
        // ...
      },

      // --------
      // LEAVING
      // --------

      beforeLeave: function (el) {
        Velocity(el, {
          translateY: this.direction === 'down' ? '100%' : '-100%',
          opacity: 0
        }, {
          duration: 300
        });
        // ...
      },
      // the done callback is optional when
      // used in combination with CSS
      leave: function (el, done) {
        Velocity(el, {
          translateY: this.direction === 'down' ? '100%' : '-100%',
          opacity: 0
        }, {
          duration: 300
        });
        // ...
        // done()
      },
      afterLeave: function (el) {
        // ...
      },
      // leaveCancelled only available with v-show
      leaveCancelled: function (el) {
        // ...
      }
    }
  }
</script>
<style scoped>
  .trans-container {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    position: absolute;
    align-items: center;
  }
</style>
```

I just simply can't do it using css. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Basic idea:

After the user clicks on the button, attach class:

```
.disappear {
  transform: translate(0, -100px);
  transition: opacity 2s, transform 2s;
  opacity: 0
}
```

And then

```
window.setTimeout(function() { 
// set display to none, and then remove .disappear
}, 2000)
```

Edit: some elaboration

Give every slide

```
transition: opacity 2s, transform 2s;
```

and position them at (page) center. All slides not shown get the `.slidedBottom` Class

Use the following classes:

```
.slidedTop {
  transform: translate(0, -100px);
  opacity: 0;
}
.slidedBottom {
  transform: translate(0, 100px);
  opacity: 0;
}
.disappear {
  opacity: 0;
}
.appear {
  opacity: 1;
}
.hidden {
  display: none; // or use the hidden attribute
}
```

For the element to fade out (upwards):

```
// add .disappear

window.setTimeout(function() { 
// remove disappear, add hidden, slidedTop
}, 2000)
```

Fade in:

```
// remove hidden, slidedBottom, add appear
window.setTimeout(function() {
// remove appear
}, 2000)
```

Comment: Instead of using a timeout, you should use the [`animationend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/animationend) event